# eclipse egit, repository unable to push, pull or fetch, after sharing the project

Tags: java, eclipse, push, egit, pull

I shared my project in eclipse, by

Right Click -> Team -> Share. In the wizard: Add the URL, user, password. Advanced -> set master remote and local -> Save and Push.

Then I tested by making some changes, and push, and it was working.

My friend used clone to get the same project. She made some changes, I tried fetch/pull, both of them gives the error: Nothing to fetch. I tried Push, which gives the error: rejected-non fast forward!

My Error Log View:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.8.0_20-ea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product



Error
Thu Aug 07 10:28:51 EDT 2014
Can't connect to any repository:
https://Andisheh86@bitbucket.org/Andisheh86/semanticsearch.git (Nothing to push.)

Warning
Thu Aug 07 10:57:38 EDT 2014
Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
```

[image: Error Log View]

The content of ".git/config"

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
url = https://Andisheh86@bitbucket.org/Andisheh86/semanticsearch.git
push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: It sounds to me as if the local branch was not configured for fetch/pull from a remote branch. Do you have the `.git/config` file from that repository?

Comment: yes, I have that and the data in that is correct based on other posts I found here.

Comment: Could you include the contents of `.git/config` in the question?

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me all the time. I think is because some of bad integration between egit and eclipse. What I do to solve this is open a terminal, go to the directory of your project and do **git pull** from the console.

The command line will work probably fine. Then, when everything is synchronized, you can go back to your eclipse and start working again from there. In most cases, after doing this eclipse works totally fine.

Comment: Thank you! It was driving me crazy, so I cloned it again!

Comment: Is there something in the Error Log view when it happens? I'm from the EGit team and it would nice to get a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EGit) with specifics, because this shouldn't happen.