# EGit: Issuing a fast-forward pull ~ How to configure fetch for a remote repository in EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, git-pull

So let me set up my scenario. I am using EGit 4.1.1 in Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse 4.5.1). My tech-savvy coworker and I have cloned the same git repository from a remote URL. My tech-savvy coworker, who prefers the command line, does his file modification using VIM, then issues the commands

```
git add .
git commit -m "Modified file"
git push
```

Now the change is in the remote repository. Now I, who am less CLI-prone and more prefer the GUI, am using EGit in Eclipse. To receive the change, I right click the project (which I originally cloned using EGit), go to Team -> Pull, and I am told that there is "**Nothing to fetch**". For sanity purposes, I have the "Git Reflog" view open, and I see that my coworker's change is not listed, and I begin to scratch my head.

So I go to the command line and I issue the command `git pull`, and voila!, it pulls in my coworkers change:

```
remote: Counting objects: 27, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Total 14 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (14/14), done.
From git://hostname.domain.com/git-repo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 123ae12..68cd2f0
Fast-forward
```

Better yet, I go back to Eclipse, and I see the change in the "Git Reflog" view, listed as

```
Commit   Commit Message     Date         Reflog Message
---------------------------------------------------------------
68cd2f0  Modified File      2015-12-23   pull: Fast-forward
```

So, I feel like what I am being told here leads me to believe that there is a Git concept that I am not familiar with - something that I'm probably just missing. So...

- Is there anything obvious I am missing here about the workings of git?
- I am assuming that fast-forward means I am just moving my HEAD forward in the same branch
- How do I accomplish this command-line "git pull" in Eclipse?

---

**Edit**: To address VonC's answer, I have added this information that is both more information and a solution to this question.

From the command line, when I run (from the repository) `cat ./.git/.gitconfig`, I get the following output:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git://hostname.domain.com/git-repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

*However*, when I go into Eclipse and look at the fetch configuration, it is blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the reflog would not show you anything *before* a fetch (in command line or Eclipse): it records changes from the *local* clone only.

Second, [check your `.gitconfig`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25205845/6309) to see how the remote origin is configured (also [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25188014/6309)).
You need to have a line for fetching:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

By default, the command line [`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) would use the current branch:

```
refs/heads/<head>:refs/heads/<branch>
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I suspect .gitconfig is not completely configured, while the command line might default the fetch refspec to `refs/heads/<head>:refs/heads/<branch>` as mentioned in http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch. We need to see the `.gitconfig` first to know more.

Answer (score 9):

To add to VonC's answer, what this means is that **I missed a step** when I originally configured the remotes for the git repo when I used EGit to configure it. Since I didn't have fetch configured for the repo, Eclipse was giving me the error "Nothing to fetch" - where perhaps it should have given me a more meaningful error like "Fetch not configured for this repository. To configure, you must..." Maybe I'll fix that later since EGit is open source.

**To fix this** in Eclipse (EGit), do the following:

1. Ensure the *Git Repositories* view is open.
2. Select the specific git repo, and expand it till the specific remote in *remotes* is expanded:
   [image: EGit Repository: Select Remote]
3. Right click the *incoming* origin and choose *Configure Fetch*
   [image: EGit Remote: Configure Fetch]
4. In the dialog, if you see no fetch configured at all, select *Add* next to the *Ref Mappings* pane
   [image: EGit Configure Fetch: Add Ref]
5. In the dialog, for *Source*, type `refs/heads/*` (despite the "Not found in remote repository" message. Select *Next*.
   [image: EGit Add Ref: Select Source]
6. For *Destination*, make sure `refs/remotes/origin/*` is filled in (it may auto-populate). Make sure *Update the local repository even if data could be lost* is checked. Click *Finish*.
   [image: EGit Add Ref: Select Destination]
7. Now in your *Configure Fetch* dialog, you will see the new ref mapping: `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. This matches what is in the .gitconfig file.
   [image: EGit Configure Fetch: Ref Added]
8. Now click *Save* if you plan to fetch later, or *Save and Fetch* if you would like you update your local repository.

I'm not totally sure why EGit didn't do this automatically, perhaps that's a question for another day.

Comment: Great feedback, in addition to my answer. +1