# EGit says "Nothing to fetch" when I try to fetch from Origin

Tags: git, fetch, egit

I'm trying to understand how **EGIT** works.

With Spring Tool Suite, created a java project, put it under version control with **EGIT** plugin and pushed it to my account on Github.

When I try to fetch (as you can see in the image) EGIT says **Nothing to fetch**.
[image]

Some guides say configure fetch with right **click->configure fetch**.

1) What does "configure fetch" mean? Does it mean binding a branch on my computer with the relative branch on the server?

2) When configuring fetch, I have to select a **source**. If I have many branches on the remote, what's the right source? There something I don't understand in this step.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is no changes to **fetch** and your local repository is up to date so there is **"Nothing to fetch"**. Could u check your remotes by typing: **`git remote -v`**? There should be your remote github repository branches. Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34521718/10921202), this problem looks similar but at first I would like to recommend you to check remotes.

Comment: Thank you, your link cleared my doubts. I made the same error of the guy that wrote the post. The error was that I hadn't 'configure the fecth'. Thank you :)